# Update Express session for multiple users, not in the request context

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I save some data belonging to the authenticated user in the session and I want that when the user object is updated in the database `users` collection, to set somehow the updated data in the session of the user. This may not happen in the *request - response* workflow. Maybe it's a random script updating user data in the database.

How to update a specific session data with the new data that is set in the database?

Currently to set the data I do:

```
req.session.userId = 7;
req.session.foo = 42;
```

Let's assume that I want to turn `42` into `43` for the session data which has `userId === 7`. How to do that?

I'm using the [`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session) module.

I know that one solution is to reload from the database the user on each request, but that would not be performant, since it would create queries that can be avoided.

What's the best way to update the session data of the user, knowing a field that was set in the session (such as the `userId`)?

I use the [`connect-mongo`](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo) store.